# Insert data from a XML into a List

Tags: list, navigation, data-view-web-part, bcs, xml

Two questions:

**Is it possible insert data from a XML doc in a SharePoint Native List?** Because I checked and is possible create a DataView from a Xml source in SP , but I can't find if it's possible to insert the data in a list (XML Node per Item list).

I don't like DataView because I want to create navigation based on values of a specific column ( *like using Navigation metadata menu and filters of a list*) and with a Dataview  I don't see how to create this dynamic navigation, **Can I define a site/list navigation based on values of a column in a DataView?**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: you can also use PowerShell to accomplish this.
Powershell has built in cmdlets to open and process XML and the SharePoint cmdlets will allow you to easily insert this data into a list.

This snippet shows how easy it can be:

> Use the [XML] type accelerator to convert results from Get-Content
>   into an XML document, and then use dotted notation to access the
>   nodes:
>
> ```
> [xml]$books = Get-Content C:\fso\Books.XML
>
> $books.catalog.book.title
> ```
>
> From: [Use PowerShell to Easily Read an XML Document](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/13/powertip-use-powershell-to-easily-read-an-xml-document.aspx)
>
> And a more detailed explanation at: [Use PowerShell to Simplify Access to XML Data](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/13/use-powershell-to-simplify-access-to-xml-data.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this out of the box.  You will need to do this using the API or Web Services.  Your code would parse the XML and then create a list with the required columns based off of the nodes in your file.

OR you can open the excel file with your xml content,then you can import the same excel sheet to sharepoint list as well.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cbea71f2-ef9a-43cd-b25d-478fa37fbcad/xml-to-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)